# Cannot install ssh on CentOS 7: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/sshd

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd

I was facing a problem with SSH and tried to reinstall it.

So first I did `yum remove openssh-server openssh-clients`, successfully.

Then I tried to reinstall it with `yum install openssh-server openssh-clients`, but I got the following error:

```
[...]
Downloading packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                              1.6 MB/s | 1.1 MB  00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing   : openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64                         1/2
Error unpacking rpm package openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
 
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/sshd: cpio: rename
  Installing   : openssh-clients-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64                        2/2
Error unpacking rpm package openssh-clients-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
 
error: openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64: install failed
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/ssh: cpio: rename
  Verifying    : openssh-clients-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64                        1/2 
  Verifying    : openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64                         2/2 

Failed:
  openssh-clients.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7   openssh-server.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7  

Complete!
```

I read that this could be a problem with an immutable flag raised in these files. And indeed when I use:
`lsattr /usr/sbin/sshd`
I get:
`----i----------- /usr/sbin/sshd`

But when I do `chattr -i /usr/sbin/sshd` and then check again with `lsattr` the `i` flag is still there.

How can I solve this and be able to install SSH again?

My CentOS version is `centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64`

I'm doing all these operations as root (su).

Comment: Check systemctl status sshd if there is still a service running stop then try again or stop it and log out then back in.

Comment: @JasonCroyle looks like indeed there is still a service running, but how can I stop it? `systemctl stop ssh` says `Failed to stop ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not loaded.` I also tried to reboot the entire system.

Comment: The command would be “sudo systemctl stop sshd” then you can try reinstalling.  If it still fails run “sudo systemctl disable sshd” then reboot and reinstall.

Comment: Now it says sshd service is "inactive (dead)" but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it hasn't been complete removed when you uninstalled it verify `systemctl status sshd` if that still show an output.  You can run “sudo systemctl stop sshd” then try reinstalling.  If it still fails run “sudo systemctl disable sshd” then reboot or atleast log out and back in and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it and `systemctl status sshd` says the service it's inactive. But I still can't change the `i` flag or install with `yum`

Comment: Also i tried removing `sshd.service` with `rm -rf /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` and status now says: `Unit sshd.service could not be found`. But still no progress. The service returns to inactive after trying to install with yum again

Comment: When all this happened had you been trying to change the ssh port or change the default ssh config if so you can try “sshd -t” this is test mode i didn’t suggest earlier because it shouldn’t be installed but give it a try if will run should return if there is any config errors.

Answer (score 0):

Granted it's a **local** PC you're accessing from shell please run:

```
sudo chattr -i /usr/bin/ssh
echo $?
sudo chattr -i /usr/sbin/sshd
echo $?
sudo killall -9 sshd
pgrep sshd
```

Now you can proceed to reinstall the openssh server and client.

```
yum install openssh-server openssh-clients
```

---

Addendum: you shouldn't use `chattr +i` to "secure" your system and let me explain why. Whenever you've been hacked, the attacker can probably get access to the root account and then he can:

- remove the immutable attribute (most hardcore Linux hackers are perfectly aware of it)
- replace any of the libraries the SSH daemon uses which will make it work how the attacker wants
- add additional daemons which will grant full access outside of SSHD
- replace the kernel or add kernel modules which will change/circumvent the SSHD behavior